# Saving a Crystal Report as a PDF within a C# class

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Newbie question.  I'm trying to write a C# class that can run a Crystal Report and save the result as a PDF file.  My method currently only contains one line, which it is failing on:

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
```

My "using" list contains:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I've installed two NuGet packages, CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine and CrystalDecisions.Shared.  I'm just trying to follow some examples I've found from web surfing, and it seems that the examples I'm looking at always include these two packages.

The error I'm receiving on the ReportDocument instantiation above is:

*"Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'. The system cannot find the file specified."*

I suspect there's something obvious; I'm missing that hasn't been installed.  I do have installed on my machine:

- Crystal Reports 2011,
- SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (32-bit),
- and Crystal Reports 2008 Runtime SP2.

I'm new to a lot of this and am not having much success finding the help I'm looking for.

Help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Did a search and found, https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrystalReports.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc/ Try installing that package with the version you need; Install-Package CrystalReports.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc -Version 13.0.2000.0 ; hope this helps

Comment: Hi Andrew.  I tried installing that package and adding it to my "using" statements, but I ended up with a different error.  ""Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'. The system cannot find the file specified."  I'm sure this can be resolved by installing another NuGet package, but I'm not sure if this is taking me down a rabbit hole.  I'm wondering why none of the other examples I'm seeing mention anything about needing the ReportAppServer NuGet packages.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this : first create instance of Crystal report, and you can simply Call Export To disk

```
RtpDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "C:\report.pdf")
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm not sure I follow when you say to create an instance of the Crystal Report.  If that means to simply create the RtpDocument variable as a ReportDocument (line of code: "ReportDocument RtpDocument;") before using the piece of code you have in your answer, this causes me to get the error, "Use of unassigned local variable 'RtpDocument'".  Thanks!

Comment: you need to use keyword new : from my VB code example :  Dim RtpDocument As New SomeReport (SomeReport is RptDocument template)

Comment: Wouldn't that just end up being the equivalent of the code from my original post?  "ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();"  Unfortunately, this is the line of code that has been failing.  It doesn't even manage to reach the ExportToDisk method you've provided for the next line of code.